# Binary search tree doesn't work

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm having a pretty confusing problem in building a binary tree. Apparently this should be an easy task but somehow I may mess up with the pointers in it.

Here's the simplified code (of course it's not the real code) :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define DIM1 2 

typedef enum {LEFT,RIGHT} direction;
typedef char tName[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];

struct Rectangle {
  tName _name; 
  struct Rectangle *_binSon[DIM1];             
};

struct Rectangle *recTree;

void insertRectToTree(char str[]){  
    struct Rectangle rect;
    struct Rectangle *point;
    struct Rectangle *parent;
    strcpy(rect._name,str);
    rect._binSon[RIGHT] = NULL;
    rect._binSon[LEFT] = NULL;
    point = &rect;
    if (recTree == NULL){
       recTree = point;
    } else {
      struct Rectangle *current;
      current = recTree;
      while (current){
          parent = current;
          if (strcmp(point -> _name, current -> _name) > 0){
              current = current -> _binSon[RIGHT];
          } else {
              current = current -> _binSon[LEFT];
          }
      }
      if (strcmp(point -> _name, parent -> _name) < 0){
          parent -> _binSon[LEFT] = point;
      } else {
          parent -> _binSon[RIGHT] = point;
      }
      }
   }

int main(){
   recTree = NULL;
   char str[] = "LIKE";
   insertRectToTree(str);
   char str2[] = "GUIDE";
   insertRectToTree(str2);
   printf(recTree -> _name);
   return 0;
}
```

As you can see, this binary tree tries to organize a record based on its name, so the smallest alphabetical order will go to the left side and so on.

The problem is, after the first insertion "LIKE", I want "GUIDE" inserted to the tree as well, with "LIKE" still as the root. However, the printf() shows that "GUIDE" takes over as its root. (In other word, "GUIDE" is the output). Any good explanation for this? Ask me if I need to add some more thing to this question. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: it's c++, but i bet it applies for c as well because i don't use any classes

Comment: Why are you putting the keyword struct in this line "struct Rectangle *current;"

Comment: yeah, i think i need to get rid of those. but it doesn't solve the problem still, sigh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the following lines

```
struct Rectangle rect;
...
point = &rect;
...
recTree = point;
```

you assign a reference to a local variable to a global pointer. After leaving the function it may no longer contain valid data.

Comment: that's true. do you have any workaround on this? i'm kinda suck in pointers quite honestly

Comment: @vandershraaf Use `point = new struct Rectangle;` and later `point -> _binSon[RIGHT] = NULL; ...` and get rid of `rect` completely.

Comment: i didn't use [new struct Rectangle] but instead [new Rectangle]. btw thanks for your response. this is the best answer since i didn't know the real problem before

Answer (score 1):

Howard is correct. But to correct the problem use new.

i.e. instead of 
`point = &rect;`

Put
`point = new struct Rectangle;`

Comment: i tried this but it has error in it. is there any other workaround?

Comment: i've tried this but [point = new Rectangle] works better. nevertheless, i'm giving upvote for your insight